# how can I store collapsed edges using CGAL

Tags: c++, qt, computational-geometry, cgal

I'm creating an application on QT-creator and using CGAL to read .off file as Linear_cell_complex_for_bgl_combinatorial_map_helper  and simplify it using edge_collapse method .
I want to store the list of collapsed edges,incident vertices, position of points , and other needed information to re-insert the removed edges again .

**my code**

```
namespace SMS = CGAL::Surface_mesh_simplification ;
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Linear_cell_complex_traits<3, Kernel> MyTraits;
typedef CGAL::Linear_cell_complex_for_bgl_combinatorial_map_helper<2, 3, MyTraits>::type LCC;

typedef boost::graph_traits<LCC>::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
typedef SMS::Edge_profile<LCC> Profile ;
struct Stats
{
  Stats() :  collapsed(0) {}
  std::size_t collapsed ;
} ;

struct My_visitor : SMS::Edge_collapse_visitor_base<LCC>
{

My_visitor( Stats* s) : stats(s){}
void OnCollapsed( Profile const&, vertex_descriptor )
  {
    ++ stats->collapsed;
  }

Stats* stats ;
};


    namespace SMS = CGAL::Surface_mesh_simplification ;

    SMS::Count_stop_predicate<LCC> stop(1000);
    Stats stats ;

    My_visitor vis(&stats) ;

 int r = SMS::edge_collapse
   (lcc
    ,stop
    ,CGAL::parameters::halfedge_index_map(get(CGAL::halfedge_index, lcc))
             .vertex_index_map(get(boost::vertex_index, lcc))
             .get_cost(SMS::Edge_length_cost<LCC>())
   .get_placement(SMS::Midpoint_placement<LCC>()).visitor(vis)
    );

 std::cout << "\nEdges collapsed: "  << stats.collapsed
            << std::endl;
```

I tried to use Edge_collapse_visitor_base to get no of collapsed edges , but I don't know to to get the information related to the collapsed edges .

I appreciate any help .

Comment: Is the info you want in vertex_descriptor in the callback?

Answer (score 2):

I have a [branch](https://github.com/afabri/cgal/tree/SMS-undo_example-GF/Surface_mesh_simplification/examples/Surface_mesh_simplification) on github where I use the visitor to record edge collapses. And I added further callbacks to the visitor so that one can undo the edge collapses. I made it work for `CGAL::Surface_mesh` as well as for OpenMesh.

Comment: I cannot find <CGAL/Surface_mesh_simplification/Edge_collapse_recorder.h> I'm using cgal 4.13 I commented here because the other github issue is closed

Comment: @n.m The branch [creates also that header files. See https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/compare/master...afabri:SMS-undo_example-GF?expand=1

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the concept that defines the visitor class: [`EdgeCollapseSimplificationVisitor`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/classEdgeCollapseSimplificationVisitor.html). If you implement the `OnCollapsing` method. Its parameter `Profile const & profile` has all the information you need.

Comment: I'm a newbie in using CGAL , I cannot find related examples to use profile methods 
when I try
std::cout <<  profile.v0() << " will collapse into "<< profile.v1()<<std::endl;
 
it's shows the following error :
no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream’} and ‘const vertex_descriptor’

Comment: Let's stop discussing here, it seems that the discussion at https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/3707 is longer than here.